# Hide Flyout on button click (DelegateCommand)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am building a Windows Store app and I have a flyout that looks like this:
[image: flyout]

The `Flyout` is functioning properly, and I am able to add a new address when I click on the "Add" `Button`.  The problem is, I want to be able to hide the `Flyout` as well.  My `DelegateCommand` is in the `ViewModel`, so I do not have a reference to the actual `View` elements.

I have tried changing the `DelegateCommand` to take a parameter, like so:

```
public DelegateCommand<object> AddAddressCommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(AddAddress, CanAddAddress); }
}

public void AddAddress(object parameter)
{
    if (_isEditing)
    {
        NewAddress.PayeeId = CurrentPayee.Id;
        _addressRepository.InsertAsync(NewAddress);
    }
    CurrentPayee.Addresses.Add(NewAddress);
    NewAddress = new Address();

    // TODO: hide Flyout
}
```

And in my XAML, I try to pass a `CommandParameter` to the `DelegateCommand` like so:

```
<Button Content="Add" 
        Command="{Binding AddAddressCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

If I pass `{RelativeSource Self}`, I get a reference to the `Button` as expected, but I haven't been able to reference anything else up the tree.  The "Add" `Button` is a child of the `Flyout`, which is attached to the "Add Address" `AppBarButton`.

Ideally, I could pass in a reference either to the `Flyout` directly, or the `AppBarButton`, so that I can call `Flyout.Hide()` when I click on the "Add" Button`.

I have tried setting the `x:Name` of the `AppBarButton` and the `Flyout` and referencing them in the `CommandParameter` like so:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddAddressFlyout}"
```

and in both cases, my parameter is `null`.  Is it possible to accomplish this using straight data binding, or am I going to have to add some sort of `Behavior`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this article useful, it demonstrates how to use a dependency property to control if the fly out is open or closed. You can then bind the dependency property to a property on your view model: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/using-windows-8-1-flyout-xaml-control-with-mvvm/

I've literally just tried it in my own app and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had bookmarked this article myself to try out later on.  I was hoping to be able to get it working directly binding to the `Flyout` or `AppBarButton` if possible, as I was trying in the original question, but it appears that I will probably have to use the dependency property route.  Glad to hear that it worked for you, it seems like it should do the trick!

Comment: Indeed, it did end up working like a charm.  Now to determine if it works with multiple flyouts in the same `View`.  I imagine it should, since more than one won't be visible at a time...

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps I'm missing a subtlety in your requirements, but I was able to close a flyout quite easily using x:Name and .Hide()

use x:Name="MyFlyout" in your `<Flyout>` tag and then close it in your C# click event by doing MyFlyout.Hide()

### XAML CODE:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout x:Name="MyFlyout">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CancelButton_Click" Margin="0,-10,-10,0">
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Cancel"/>
                        </Button>
                            <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

### C# CODE

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyFlyout.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am no longer using the `Flyout` method for this, but I was trying to avoid using code-behind at the time, in sticking with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: +1 Makes more sense to add a quick event and hide it, instead of adding a few classes and then a lot of boiler plate code for somethings so small.

Comment: You can have code-behind in MVVM pattern, code behind is part of the View and if your code relates strictly to the UI it is perfectly ok to have some of it there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using AttachableProperties.  I will send two that I have written that are easy to use and accomplish this goal.  The first attaches to the Flyout and references a Button.  When the button is clicked it closes the Flyout.

The second attaches to the Button and references the Flyout (useful if the buttons in the Flyout are part of a data template).  The same effect occurs only in this case you can have multiple buttons that will close the flyout when pressed.

First, I have the custom extension method in my project which I use in the example:

```
public static class XAMLExtensions
{
    public static T GetParent<T>(this DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parentDependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

        switch (parentDependencyObject)
        {
            case null:
                return null;
            case T parent:
                return parent;
            default:
                return GetParent<T>(parentDependencyObject);
        }        
    }
}
```

Then the attachable properties...
**Attachable Properties**

```
public class FlyoutAttach : DependencyObject
{
    private const string CloseButtonPropertyName = "CloseButton";
    private const string CanCloseFlyoutPropertyName = "CanCloseFlyout";
    private const string ClosedCommandPropertyName = "ClosedCommand";
    private const string ClosedCommandParameterPropertyName = "ClosedCommandParameter";

    public static Button GetCloseButton(Flyout flyout) => (Button)flyout.GetValue(CloseButtonProperty);
    public static void SetCloseButton(Flyout flyout, Button value) => flyout.SetValue(CloseButtonProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(CloseButtonPropertyName,
                                            typeof(Button),
                                            typeof(FlyoutAttach),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(null,
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
                                            {
                                                if (s is Flyout flyout && e.NewValue is Button button)
                                                {
                                                    button.Click -= buttonClick;
                                                    button.Click += buttonClick;
                                                }
                                                void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) => flyout.Hide();
                                            })));


    public static bool GetCanCloseFlyout(Button button) => (bool)button.GetValue(CanCloseFlyoutProperty);
    public static void SetCanCloseFlyout(Button button, bool value) => button.SetValue(CanCloseFlyoutProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanCloseFlyoutProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(CanCloseFlyoutPropertyName,
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(FlyoutAttach),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(false,
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
                                            {
                                                if (s is Button button && e.NewValue is bool canCloseFlyout)
                                                {
                                                    button.Click -= buttonClick;
                                                    if (canCloseFlyout) button.Click += buttonClick;
                                                }

                                                void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
                                                {
                                                    var flyoutPresenter = button.GetParent<FlyoutPresenter>();
                                                    if (flyoutPresenter?.Parent is Popup popup)
                                                        popup.IsOpen = false;
                                                }
                                            })));


    public static ICommand GetClosedCommand(Flyout flyout) => (ICommand)flyout.GetValue(ClosedCommandProperty);
    public static void SetClosedCommand(Flyout flyout, ICommand value) => flyout.SetValue(ClosedCommandProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosedCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(ClosedCommandPropertyName, 
                                            typeof(ICommand), 
                                            typeof(FlyoutAttach), 
                                            new PropertyMetadata(null,
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
                                            {
                                                if (s is Flyout flyout && e.NewValue is ICommand command)
                                                {
                                                    flyout.Closed -= flyoutClosed;
                                                    flyout.Closed += flyoutClosed;

                                                    void flyoutClosed(object sender, object ee)
                                                    {
                                                        var commandParameter = flyout.GetValue(ClosedCommandParameterProperty);
                                                        if (command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
                                                            command.Execute(commandParameter);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            })));


    public static object GetClosedCommandParameter(Flyout flyout) => flyout.GetValue(ClosedCommandParameterProperty);
    public static void SetClosedCommandParameter(Flyout flyout, object value) => flyout.SetValue(ClosedCommandParameterProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosedCommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(ClosedCommandParameterPropertyName, typeof(object), typeof(FlyoutAttach), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

**In the View**

```
<Flyout Attachable:FlyoutAttach.CloseButton="{Binding ElementName=button}">
     <Button x:Name="button" />
</Flyout>
```

**OR**

```
<Flyout>
     <Button Attachable:FlyoutAttach.CanCloseFlyout="True" />
</Flyout>
```